# Is it possible to have F# able to recognize an overlap of DU and use the right one itself?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

```ml
type GenericResult =
    | Ok
    | Error of string

type LoginResult =
    | Ok
    | UserNotFound
    | WrongPassword

let check something:GenericResult =
    match something with
    //| true -> Ok // error:This expression was expected to be of type "GenericREsult" but here has type "LoginResult"
    | true -> GenericResult.Ok // I'm forced to specify GenericResult.Ok
    | false -> Error "aargg!"

let checkLogin something:LoginResult =
    match something with
    | true -> Ok // here I don't need to specify the DU because this is defined after
    | _ -> WrongPassword
```

I'd like to use just "Ok" in both the methods, without the need to specify the DU.
I see that in case of clashing of the value the last one is the "predefined".

Ideally I'd like to have a sort of *inheritance*
to reuse part of a DU in another DU.
For example:

```ml
type GenericResult =
    | Ok
    | Error of string

type LoginResult =
    //| GenericResult.Ok
    | UserNotFound
    | WrongPassword

type SaveResult =
    | Created
    | Updated
    //| GenericResult.Error


let checkLogin something: LoginResult | GenericResult.Ok =
    match something with
    | true -> Ok 
    | _ -> WrongPassword
```

[EDIT]
The real scenario where I feel the need for this feature is this with 3 different results from 3 different logic classes.
There will be in the future more cases so the multiplication of duplicated DU values will increase.

```ml
// DUs ordered from the most specific to the most generic

type BalanceUpdateResult = 
| Created
| Updated
| InvalidRequest of string

type DeleteResult =
| Ok
| InvalidRequest of string

type Result<'T> =
| Ok of 'T
| NotValid of string
| Error of string
```

The goal is to have a clean *match* syntax in the consumer, where the value of the DU will evenctually be used to raise an exception or to return the created value, for example.

```ml
// balance update function (result is BalanceUpdateResult):
    match result with
    | Created -> this.createOkWithStatus 201 
    | Updated -> this.createOkWithStatus 200
    | InvalidRequest error -> this.createErrorForConflict error

// company creation function (result is Result<Company>):
    match result with 
    | Result.Ok newItem -> 
        context.Logger.Log $"Company created. New Id:{newItem.Id}, Name:{newItem.Name}."
        this.createCreated newItem
    | NotValid error -> base.createErrorForConflict error
    | Error error -> base.createError error
```

Here, for example, InvalidRequest is not accepted in the second case because it belongs to the wrong DU.
Having to specify the DU everywhere results in a mess like the following example (see the many **Result<_>.**):

```ml
    interface ICompanyLogic with
        member this.Create(company:Company):Result<Company> =
            match normalize company |> validate with
            | NotValid msg -> Result<_>.NotValid msg
            | Valid validCompany ->
                match companyRepository.Exists(validCompany.Name) with 
                | true -> Result<_>.NotValid($"A company with name \"{validCompany.Name}\" already exists.")
                | _ -> 
                    let newCompany = assignNewId validCompany
                    companyRepository.Create(newCompany)
                    Result<_>.Ok(newCompany)
            
        member this.Update (company:Company):Result<Company> =
            let checkNameExists company = 
                match companyRepository.GetByName company.Name with
                | Some c when c.Id <> company.Id -> NotValid $"A company with name \"{company.Name}\" already exists."
                | _ -> Valid company
         
            match normalize company |> validate with
            | NotValid msg -> Result<_>.NotValid msg
            | Valid c -> match checkNameExists c with
                         | Valid c -> companyRepository.Update c; Result<_>.Ok c
                         | NotValid msg -> Result<_>.NotValid msg
```

Comment: well there are techniques to do this sort of thing, but they come at a cost and u will have to abandon native F# DUs for what OO'ers would call visitors.

Comment: I'm also baffled why someone voted this post down, so Ive voted it back up, its actually a very interesting problem related to the "expression problem"

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to start with a generic `Result` type that has a type parameter representing the error type:

```
type Result<'TError> =
    | Ok
    | Error of 'TError
```

This allows you to use different types for representing errors, including `string`, but also another DU to capture more specific error types. You can then define `GenericResult` and `LoginResult` as two type aliases:

```
type LoginError =
    | UserNotFound
    | WrongPassword

type GenericResult = Result<string>
type LoginResult = Result<LoginError>
```

To report a login error, you would now use `Error WrongPassword` to wrap the specific error in the generic `Error` constructor. The implementation of your two functions looks as follows:

```
let check something:GenericResult =
  match something with
  | true -> Ok
  | false -> Error "aargg!"

let checkLogin something:LoginResult =
  match something with
  | true -> Ok
  | _ -> Error WrongPassword
```

Comment: Yes, that, or just use `Option<'t>`. No one wants to maintain those error strings anyway :) And once they are there, someone wants error codes, too, because of reasons.

Comment: You could just as well use exceptions because they eliminate all the error propagation boilerplate. The answer is always - it depends...

Comment: This solution does not cover all the scenarios I have (see my example with SaveResult DU having multiple successful values and the added code example too)
but it is helping me to remove some duplicated values and it shown a possibility I haven't probably considered.  
Maybe the best thing (to avoid specify the DU for duplicates) is just create the right basic DU with generics that can be reused/shared.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike TypeScript union type, F# DU are meant to be composed and not extensible - see [Thomas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257775/8634147) for a solution using this approach.

Since F# does not offer a direct solution, you may consider renaming cases like `InvalidRequest` in order to be more specific and to help differentiate them when reading the code. With these specific names, you can also merge all result types into a big `Event` DU like what's usually done in an event sourced system:

```ml
type Event = 
// BalanceUpdateResult
| BalanceCreated
| BalanceUpdated
| BalanceUpdateError of string

// DeleteResult
| DeleteOk
| DeleteError of string

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as explained by [Romain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263076/996946) multiple DUs cannot solve my problem.
I decided to use the built-in [`type Result<'T,'TError>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results).
It allows me to avoid create many DUs that inevitably will have clash of names, forcing the use the full DU prefix in the code.
I solved the problem that drove me to create custom DUs with the inspiring example from [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257775/996946) reply.
(with Result<*,*>) I have the possibility to have dinstinct Errors or Oks.
(note the `Result<unit,_>` and the `Result<BalanceUpdateRequest,_>`)

```js
type ICompanyLogic =
    abstract member Create:Company -> Result<Company, string> // CreateResult
    abstract member Update:Company -> Result<Company, string> // UpdateResult
    abstract member Delete:string -> Result<unit,string>  // DeleteResult
    
type BalanceUpdateResult = 
| Created
| Updated

type IBalanceLogic =
    abstract member CreateOrUpdate: request:BalanceUpdateRequest -> Result<BalanceUpdateResult, string>
```

Apart `BalanceUpdateResult` all the other DUs where replaced buy the `Result<'T,'TError>`.
I just maintained a couple one for specific tasks:

```js
type CompanyValidation = Valid of Company | NotValid of string
type ValidateResult = Valid | NotValid of string
```

In the end with this solution:

- I don't need to define many DUs
- I can customize the Result... within as many values I want (storing a sub-DU in the Ok or Error union case)
- I don't need to use prefix or use synonims to avoid clash (code result much cleaner)